# Java collection query : creating array of mkdir commands

Tags: java, collections

I have a `LinkedHashSet` of `String` as below:

```
Set<String> dirSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
```

There are 12 `String` elements in above `Set` as below:

```
root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir1/
root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir1/subDir/
root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir2/
root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir2/subDir/
root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir3/
root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir3/subDir/
root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir4/
root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir4/subDir/
root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir5/
root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir5/subDir/
root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir6/
root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir6/subDir/
```

I want to write a method to iterate through above `Set` in such a way that output of the method is a `String` `Array` containing commands to create above directory structure.

Output `String` `Array` should contain `String` elements as below:

```
mkdir root/
mkdir root/dir1/
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir1/
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir1/subDir/
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir2/
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir2/subDir/
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir3/
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir3/subDir/
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir4/
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir4/subDir/
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir5/
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir5/subDir/
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir6/
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir6/subDir/
```

I am able to reach `dir5` level and then go one level in i.e. till `baseDir1/subDir/` by iterating through the Set and taking help of `String.split()` method to create tokens.

However, I am not able to tackle when I again have to go a level up (baseDir2, baseDir3, etc.)

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Please use the `java.nio.file.Path` class when working with file paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
"root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir1/",
"root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir1/subDir/", 
"root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir2/", 
"root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir2/subDir/", 
"root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir3/", 
"root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir3/subDir/",
"root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir4/", 
"root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir4/subDir/",
"root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir5/", 
"root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir5/subDir/", 
"root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir6/",
"root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir6/subDir/");

Set<String> dirSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(list); 
Set<Path> allDirs = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for (String file : dirSet) {
    recur(allDirs, Paths.get(file));
} 

for (Path path : allDirs) {
    System.out.println("mkdir " + path);
}

...

public static void recur(Set<Path> paths, Path path) {
    if (path == null)
        return;
    recur(paths, path.getParent());
    paths.add(path);
}
```

Use a recursive method. Return if the `Path` passed is `null` otherwise recur on its parent. Then add the path.

Because we use a `LinkedHashSet` that preserves order, the first path added will be the `root` directory of the `Path` and then each child of that. You can use a `TreeSet` too.

It prints

```
mkdir root
mkdir root\dir1
mkdir root\dir1\dir2
mkdir root\dir1\dir2\dir3
mkdir root\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4
mkdir root\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5
mkdir root\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\baseDir1
mkdir root\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\baseDir1\subDir
mkdir root\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\baseDir2
mkdir root\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\baseDir2\subDir
mkdir root\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\baseDir3
mkdir root\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\baseDir3\subDir
mkdir root\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\baseDir4
mkdir root\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\baseDir4\subDir
mkdir root\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\baseDir5
mkdir root\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\baseDir5\subDir
mkdir root\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\baseDir6
mkdir root\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\baseDir6\subDir
```

You can always order them as you want. `Path` might have an internal ordering logic too.

Comment: Why all this fuss, when there is the [File.mkdirs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) call?

Comment: @ppeterka66 I don't know, but OP explained in a comment to another answer that his requirement was a little more complicated than that. Maybe the point is just printing it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use mkdirs instead of mkdir:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()

Comment: At least find the javadoc for Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `mkdir` unix commands then you could cheat and use `mkdir -p` which creates the necessary parent directories along the way.

```
mkdir -p root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir1/
mkdir -p root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir1/subDir/
```

etc.  Or just create the directories in Java using `File.mkdirs()` which does the same thing.

To answer the actual question, I would use an intermediate structure such as a `TreeSet`

```
TreeSet<String> mkdirCmds = new TreeSet<String>();
for(String origPath : dirSet) {
  if(origPath.endsWith("/")) {
    // strip trailing slash if there is one
    origPath = origPath.substring(0, origPath.length() - 1);
  }
  mkdirCmds.add("mkdir " + origPath);
  int lastSlash = origPath.lastIndexOf('/');
  while(lastSlash >= 0) {
    mkdirCmds.add("mkdir " + origPath.substring(0, lastSlash));
    lastSlash = origPath.lastIndexOf('/', lastSlash - 1);
  }
}
String[] result = mkdirCmds.toArray(new String[0]);
```

This will give you a list of `mkdir` commands for all the original paths plus their parents, grandparents, etc. with no duplicates (because `mkdirCmds` is a Set) and with parents listed before their children (because `TreeSet<String>` is lexicographically sorted).

For your original input it will produce

```
mkdir root
mkdir root/dir1
mkdir root/dir1/dir2
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir1
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir1/subDir
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir2
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir2/subDir
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir3
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir3/subDir
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir4
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir4/subDir
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir5
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir5/subDir
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir6
mkdir root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/baseDir6/subDir
```

Comment: I have generalized the actual issue I am facing. So, I want exactly what I have described in my question. How to get second set of Strings in a array given first set of Strings in a HashSet...

Comment: @NikunjChauhan I've added a possible solution using a TreeSet